# Delete specific row from database

Tags: android

I am trying to delete a specific row in database. Using the following query:

```
    Uri myUri = Uri.parse("content://com.idan.datastorageprovider/maps");
    this.getContentResolver().delete(myUri, "ROUTE_NAME="+routeName,null);
```

In my database I have 2 columns: `ROUTE_NAME`,`ROUTE_PATH`.

I want to delete a row by the column `ROUTE_NAME`, while I give it a value of which row in that column I want to delete.
I don't errors, but the row is still there..

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Idan.

Comment: could you add more code, specifically the delete(..) of your content resolver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution:

```
String where="ROUTE_NAME" + "=?";
this.getContentResolver().delete(myUri,where, new String[] {nameOfValInColumn});
```